# Make Flutter app on Windows a drop target to accept files

Tags: c++, windows, flutter

My aim was to provide functionality for a [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/) app on Windows to accept drag-and-dropped files.
Flutter apps are written in Dart and compiled to native code, but since this is a cross-platform framework there needs to be a native part - the runner app - which kickstarts the Dart part of the app.

So I changed the C++ code of the Windows runner app to support drag and drop. The code works but I have very little C++ experience, so I likely

1. made mistakes
2. implemented anti-patterns
3. created memory leaks
4. introduced performance issues
5. all of the above

Here's the code, please be gentle with me:

**flutter_window.h**

```
#ifndef RUNNER_FLUTTER_WINDOW_H_
#define RUNNER_FLUTTER_WINDOW_H_

#include <flutter/dart_project.h>
#include <flutter/flutter_view_controller.h>

#include <memory>

#include "run_loop.h"
#include "win32_window.h"

// A window that does nothing but host a Flutter view.
class FlutterWindow : public Win32Window, public IDropTarget {
 public:
  // Creates a new FlutterWindow driven by the |run_loop|, hosting a
  // Flutter view running |project|.
  explicit FlutterWindow(RunLoop* run_loop,
                         const flutter::DartProject& project);
  virtual ~FlutterWindow();

 protected:
  // Win32Window:
  bool OnCreate() override;
  void OnDestroy() override;
  LRESULT MessageHandler(HWND window, UINT const message, WPARAM const wparam,
                         LPARAM const lparam) noexcept override;

  // IUnknown implementation
  HRESULT __stdcall QueryInterface (REFIID iid, void ** ppvObject);
  ULONG __stdcall AddRef (void);
  ULONG __stdcall Release (void);

  // IDropTarget implementation
  HRESULT __stdcall DragEnter(IDataObject * pDataObject, DWORD grfKeyState, POINTL pt, DWORD * pdwEffect);
  HRESULT __stdcall DragOver(DWORD grfKeyState, POINTL pt, DWORD * pdwEffect);
  HRESULT __stdcall DragLeave(void);
  HRESULT __stdcall Drop(IDataObject * pDataObject, DWORD grfKeyState, POINTL pt, DWORD * pdwEffect);

 private:
  // The run loop driving events for this window.
  RunLoop* run_loop_;

  // The project to run.
  flutter::DartProject project_;

  // The Flutter instance hosted by this window.
  std::unique_ptr<flutter::FlutterViewController> flutter_controller_;

  // the D&D registered object
  HWND _hwndRegistered;

  // helper function to convert 16-bit wstring to utf-8 encoded string
  std::string utf8_encode(const std::wstring &wstr);
  
};

#endif  // RUNNER_FLUTTER_WINDOW_H_
```

**flutter_window.cpp**

```
#include "flutter_window.h"

#include <flutter/method_channel.h>
#include <flutter/plugin_registrar_windows.h>
#include <flutter/standard_method_codec.h>

#include <optional>

#include "flutter/generated_plugin_registrant.h"

FlutterWindow::FlutterWindow(RunLoop *run_loop,
                             const flutter::DartProject &project)
    : run_loop_(run_loop), project_(project) {}

const char kChannelName[] = "desktop_drop";

std::unique_ptr<flutter::MethodChannel<>> channel;

FlutterWindow::~FlutterWindow() {}

bool FlutterWindow::OnCreate()
{
  if (!Win32Window::OnCreate())
  {
    return false;
  }

  RECT frame = GetClientArea();

  // The size here must match the window dimensions to avoid unnecessary surface
  // creation / destruction in the startup path.
  flutter_controller_ = std::make_unique<flutter::FlutterViewController>(
      frame.right - frame.left, frame.bottom - frame.top, project_);
  // Ensure that basic setup of the controller was successful.
  if (!flutter_controller_->engine() || !flutter_controller_->view())
  {
    return false;
  }
  RegisterPlugins(flutter_controller_->engine());
  run_loop_->RegisterFlutterInstance(flutter_controller_->engine());
  SetChildContent(flutter_controller_->view()->GetNativeWindow());

  //DnD: Initialize OLE
  OleInitialize(nullptr);

  //DnD: Register Drag & Drop
  if (SUCCEEDED(RegisterDragDrop(flutter_controller_->view()->GetNativeWindow(), this)))
  {
    _hwndRegistered = flutter_controller_->view()->GetNativeWindow();
  }

  channel = std::make_unique<flutter::MethodChannel<flutter::EncodableValue>>(
      flutter_controller_->engine()->messenger(), kChannelName,
      &flutter::StandardMethodCodec::GetInstance());

  return true;
}

void FlutterWindow::OnDestroy()
{
  if (flutter_controller_)
  {
    run_loop_->UnregisterFlutterInstance(flutter_controller_->engine());
    flutter_controller_ = nullptr;
  }

  //DnD: Unregister Drag & Drop
  if (_hwndRegistered)
  {
    RevokeDragDrop(_hwndRegistered);
    _hwndRegistered = NULL;
  }

  //DnD: Uninitialize OLE
  OleUninitialize();

  Win32Window::OnDestroy();
}

LRESULT
FlutterWindow::MessageHandler(HWND hwnd, UINT const message,
                              WPARAM const wparam,
                              LPARAM const lparam) noexcept
{
  // Give Flutter, including plugins, an opportunity to handle window messages.
  if (flutter_controller_)
  {
    std::optional<LRESULT> result =
        flutter_controller_->HandleTopLevelWindowProc(hwnd, message, wparam,
                                                      lparam);
    if (result)
    {
      return *result;
    }
  }

  switch (message)
  {
  case WM_FONTCHANGE:
    flutter_controller_->engine()->ReloadSystemFonts();
    break;
  }

  return Win32Window::MessageHandler(hwnd, message, wparam, lparam);
}

//DnD: Implement IUnknown
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE
FlutterWindow::QueryInterface(REFIID riid, _COM_Outptr_ void **ppvObject)
{

  return S_OK;
}

//DnD: Implement IUnknown
ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE FlutterWindow::AddRef()
{
  return 0;
}

//DnD: Implement IUnknown
ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE FlutterWindow::Release()
{
  return 0;
}

//DnD: Implement IDropTarget
HRESULT __stdcall FlutterWindow::DragEnter(IDataObject *pDataObject, DWORD grfKeyState,
                                           POINTL pt, DWORD *pdwEffect)
{
  channel.get()->InvokeMethod("entered", nullptr);
  // TODO: Implement
  return S_OK;
}

//DnD: Implement IDropTarget
HRESULT __stdcall FlutterWindow::DragOver(DWORD grfKeyState, POINTL pt, DWORD *pdwEffect)
{
  channel.get()->InvokeMethod("updated", nullptr);
  // TODO: Implement
  return S_OK;
}

//DnD: Implement IDropTarget
HRESULT __stdcall FlutterWindow::DragLeave(void)
{
  // TODO: Implement
  channel.get()->InvokeMethod("exited", nullptr);
  return S_OK;
}

//DnD: Implement IDropTarget
HRESULT __stdcall FlutterWindow::Drop(IDataObject *pDataObject, DWORD grfKeyState, POINTL pt, DWORD *pdwEffect)
{
  //wchar_t caFileName[MAX_PATH];
  FORMATETC fmte = {CF_HDROP, NULL, DVASPECT_CONTENT,
                    -1, TYMED_HGLOBAL};
  STGMEDIUM stgm;
  if (SUCCEEDED(pDataObject->GetData(&fmte, &stgm)))
  {
    HDROP hDropInfo = reinterpret_cast<HDROP>(stgm.hGlobal);

    // Get the number of files
    UINT nNumOfFiles = DragQueryFileW(hDropInfo, 0xFFFFFFFF, NULL, 0);

    flutter::EncodableList list = {};

    wchar_t sItem[MAX_PATH];
    for (UINT nIndex = 0; nIndex < nNumOfFiles; ++nIndex)
    {
      //fetch the length of the path
      UINT cch = DragQueryFileW(hDropInfo, nIndex, NULL, 0);

      //fetch the path and store it in 16bit wide char
      DragQueryFileW(hDropInfo, nIndex, (LPWSTR)sItem, cch + 1);

      std::wstring pathInfoUtf16(sItem, cch);
      std::string pathInfoUtf8 = FlutterWindow::utf8_encode(pathInfoUtf16);
      list.push_back(flutter::EncodableValue(pathInfoUtf8));
    }

    DragFinish(hDropInfo);

    ReleaseStgMedium(&stgm);

    channel.get()->InvokeMethod("dropped", std::make_unique<flutter::EncodableValue>(list));
  }
  return S_OK;
}

// helper function to convert 16-bit wstring to utf-8 encoded string
std::string FlutterWindow::utf8_encode(const std::wstring &wstr)
{
  if (wstr.empty())
    return std::string();
  int size_needed = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, &wstr[0], (int)wstr.size(), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
  std::string strTo(size_needed, 0);
  WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, &wstr[0], (int)wstr.size(), &strTo[0], size_needed, NULL, NULL);
  return strTo;
}
```

Most of this code is auto-generated when creating a new Flutter project on Windows.
Everything that is annotated with `//DnD:` is my code.

I specifically would like to know whether I implemented the `IUnknown` and `IDropTarget` interfaces correctly.
The base line for my app is Windows 10 64 bit, so I don't need to be compatible with older versions of Windows.

Comment: We may not be able to spot memory leaks unless the code that calls the functions is included (main?). Excellent first question other than that.

Comment: Unfortunately it's impossible to provide all files to run this example. To be able to run it, one has to set up the flutter framework on Windows (https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows) and then create an empty project. The above files (flutter_window.h and flutter_window.cpp) are part of each flutter app and their contents can be replaced with the above code.